# Why suddenly minimum image size for og:image Facebook OG

Tags: facebook

The [developer page of Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) tells me:

> If your image is smaller than 600 x 315 px, it will still display in
>   the link page post, but the size will be much smaller.

If I do this [FB Debug Fetch](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcaesarsbeauty.nl) my preferred og:image is not showing, Facebook tells me:

> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big
>   enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and
>   use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from
>   Facebook.

QS1) Why is there now suddenly a minimum size required?
QS2) Why, if 200x200px is the minimum, is FB not having any trouble with my 140x140 image in this FB Debug Fetch? UPDATE: I just did the  fetch again and now suddenly I get the same warning here, so I quess only QS1 remains > or is Facebook just corrupt and not always giving the correct information?

Comment: Suddenly? It been there for at least a year I think. If you don't give an image larger than 200x200 Facebook may pick another image on the page

Comment: @WizKid, I don't mean suddenly in that context, I mean that on their developer page, they don't say a word about this minimum size requirement of 200 x 200, they say on that page that if the image is smaller then 600 x 315, it will still be displayed. Now I expect my image 140 x 140 to work, but when doing the debug, 'suddenly' information about the 200 x 200 minimum requirement pops up.

Comment: Ah, please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs so we can update the docs

Comment: Done: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/916055835080418